# Command RelativeSource not working in Xamarin

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have Binding Data problem in subpages. I have a Page that shows a list of products. When clicking on the product it will go to the Product Details subpage. Everything works fine:

**Product.xaml**

```
<RefreshView x:DataType="locals:DashboardViewModel" Padding="0" Command="{Binding LoadDashboardCommand}" IsRefreshing="{Binding IsBusy, Mode=OneWay}">
    <StackLayout BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding ProductNew}">
        <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Frame x:DataType="model:Product">
                    <StackLayout>
                        <Label FontSize="14" MaxLines="2" LineBreakMode="TailTruncation" HeightRequest="40" Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                    </StackLayout>
                    <Frame.GestureRecognizers>
                        <TapGestureRecognizer NumberOfTapsRequired="1" 
                            Command="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type locals:DashboardViewModel}}, Path=ProductTappedView}" 
                            CommandParameter="{Binding .}" />
                    </Frame.GestureRecognizers>
                </Frame>
            </DataTemplate>
        </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
    </StackLayout>
</RefreshView>
```

**Product.xaml.cs**

```
DashboardViewModel dashboardViewModel;
public Product()
{
    BindingContext = dashboardViewModel = new DashboardViewModel(Navigation);
    dashboardViewModel.OnAppearing();
}
```

**DashboardViewModel.cs**

```
public class DashboardViewModel : BaseDashboardViewModel
{
    public Command LoadDashboardCommand { get; }
    public Command ProductTappedView { get; }
    public ObservableCollection<Product> ProductNew { get; }
    public DashboardViewModel(INavigation _navigation)
    {

        LoadDashboardCommand = new Command(async () => await ExecuteLoadDashboardCommand());
        ProductNew = new ObservableCollection<Product>();
        ProductTappedView = new Command<Product>(OnViewDetailProduct);
        Navigation = _navigation;
    }
    private async void OnViewDetailProduct(Product detailProduct)
    {
        await Navigation.PushAsync(new ProductDetail(detailProduct));
    }
    ............
}
```

**Next in my Productdetail page show product details. I have Read more. When clicked it will redirect to another subpage: ContentDetailProd.xaml**

**ProductDetail.xaml**

```
<ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <locals:ViewDetailProductViewModel/>
</ContentPage.BindingContext>
<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout Padding="15">
        <Label Text="{Binding ProductNews.Name}" FontFamily="RobotoMedium" FontSize="18" TextTransform="Uppercase"/>
        <Label Text="Read more"/>
        <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
            <TapGestureRecognizer NumberOfTapsRequired="1" Command="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type locals:ViewDetailProductViewModel}}, Path=ContentProductTappedView}" CommandParameter="{Binding .}" />
        </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

**ViewDetailProductViewModel.cs**

```
public class ViewDetailProductViewModel : BaseDashboardViewModel
{
    public Command ContentProductTappedView { get;}
    public ViewDetailProductViewModel()
    {
        ProductNews = new Product();
        ContentProductTappedView = new Command<Product>(OnViewContentDetailProduct);
    }
    private async void OnViewContentDetailProduct(Product detailProduct)
    {
        await Navigation.PushAsync(new ContentDetailProd(detailProduct));
    }
}
```

**ContentDetailProd.xaml.cs**

```
public ContentDetailProd(Product detailProduct)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    //Load Readmore
}
```

**However when I Debug it actually doesn't run on the event: `ContentProductTappedView` and as a result it doesn't redirect to the `ContentDetailProd.xaml` page. I've tried everything but still can't solve the problem.**

Looking forward to everyone's help. Thanks

Comment: you're making this much more complex than it needs to be.  `"{Binding ContentProductTappedView}"` should work

Comment: I still don't understand your answer. Can you be more clear with your full answer. Thank you.

Comment: use the binding expression I just gave you.  There is no need for the complex binding expression that you are using

Comment: Where you are doing `"Binding Source={RelativeSource..., Path=ProductTappedView}"`, replace all that with what Jason suggests. Inside an `ItemTemplate`, the BindingContext should be the individual item model `ViewDetailProductViewModel`, so you can refer directly to its properties.

Comment: I was not able to reproduce this issue with the code you provided. Could you provide a completed sample for me? It seems you pass the data through a Page Constructor. The link below would be helpful. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/hierarchical#passing-data-when-navigating And what is the Product for the  `ObservableCollection`? Is it the product contentpage or a Model for the product contentpage?

Comment: @Wendy Zang - MSFT answered exactly what I was looking for. And I solved the problem. Thank you very much.

Comment: Sorry for the late. I have updated the answer. I have another question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71716056/swipe-down-to-close-popup-not-working-with-carouselview-in-xamarin. Looking forward to your help. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed like this based on the documentation @Wendy Zang - MSFT provided. Everything looks good.

**ProductDetail.xaml**

```
<StackLayout x:Name="_readmore" Padding="15">
    <Label Text="{Binding ProductNews.Name}" FontFamily="RobotoMedium" FontSize="18" TextTransform="Uppercase"/>
    <Label x:Name="_content" MaxLines="2" LineBreakMode="TailTruncation" Text="{Binding ProductNews.Contents}" FontFamily="RobotoMedium" FontSize="18" TextTransform="Uppercase"/>
    <Label Text="Read more"/>
    <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
        <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="_readmore_Tapped" />
    </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
</StackLayout>
```

**ProductDetail.xaml.cs**

```
private async void _readmore_Tapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var contentget = _content.Text;      

    var detailProduct = new Product
    {
        Contents = contentget,
    };          

    var detailContentPage = new ContentDetailProd(detailProduct);
    detailContentPage.BindingContext = detailProduct;
    await Navigation.PushAsync(detailContentPage);
}
```

**ContentDetailProd.xaml.cs**

```
public ContentDetailProd(Product detailProduct)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    //Load Readmore
    
    if (detailProduct != null)
    {
        _contentmore.Text = detailProduct.Contents;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass the data through a Page Constructor, you could refer to the link below. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/hierarchical#passing-data-when-navigating